# Should I include reCaptcha branding on ALL pages, or just on the login form?

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I know one can hide the reCaptcha badge as long as one shows the reCaptcha branding, like explained here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-badge.-what-is-allowed

But I do not understand if I have to display this branding on every page of my application or not.

I did not find any answers to this questions online, thanks for helping.

Comment: When they say user flow, they mean only controls that involve recaptcha. Check https://thamesandhudson.com/ and https://www.karger.com/company the branding is only used below the text box that utilizes recaptcha, but not other pages

Comment: Thank you. I use the recaptcha only on the log in controls.

Comment: But I was thinking that google's scripts are running on every page of my app, collecting user's statistics. Even though I do a reCaptcha verification only on the log in. Does it make any sense what I am saying?

Comment: Your usage of Google Analytics on other pages is covered by different requirements, both from Google and the privacy laws in your country and your users.

Comment: I was not referring to Google Analytics. The way reCaptcha works is this: google is running some scripts in the background, collecting user data. When you trigger a reCaptcha request for a certain action (for example: login), you send that collected data to google. Even though I trigger this verification on log in page only, I am running the reCaptcha scripts on every page of my app. So I am not talking about google analytics.

Comment: If your country law requires notification or pop up for those activities, then you're required to notify the user. Google on its own doesn't care about it, just look at the two example sites, they don't put recaptcha notification on all pages.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support. Why not post an official answer and let me accept it?